# Como faço para carregar uma fonte externa num documento CSS/HTML?

Tags: css, html5, css-font-face

Estou tentando importar uma fonte externa para um arquivo `CSS`

Então, esse é o meu código `CSS`:

```
body{
    background-color: white
}

@font-face { 
   font-family: 'devgothic';
   src: url('/fonts/devgothic.eot');
   src: local('devgothic'), local('devgothic'), url('/fonts/devgothic.ttf') format('truetype');
}

.fonte {
    font-family: 'devgothic';
    color: purple;
}
```

Aparentemente, a estrutura de pastas está correta, mas simplesmente não funciona.

Comment: Precisa ver se o servidor web está configurado para dar o mime-type certo para estas extensões que você está usando de fonte. Nos meus servidores apache eu tive que cadastrar quase todas manualmente. Faça seu teste com uma fonte de outro domínio, para ver se muda o comportamento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está um tanto errado o modo que está fazendo. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Calibri';
    src: url('fonts/Calibri.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Calibri.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Calibri.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Calibri.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/Calibri.svg#Calibri') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.palavra{
   font-family: "Calibri";
}
```