# Como alterar fonte no textarea usando javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tem como mudar a fonte do texto de um textarea usando javascript?

Comment: eu alterei a sua pergunta para o que era antes, pois ela já recebeu respostas que resolvem a sua pergunta inicial, por isso você não deve alterar para um contexto diferente, ou então todo mundo que respondeu irá ter que editar obrigatoriamente suas respostas. Caso você não tenha ficado satisfeito, abra uma nova pergunta com os detalhes que você queria, ou então procure uma pergunta existente que satisfaça a sua duvida.

Comment: Sim, tem como alterar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando Jquery:

```
$('textarea').css('font-family', 'Arial');
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
$('div').on('click', function(){

  $('textarea').css('font-family', 'Arial');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>Depois de 10 anos o menino virou adulto.</textarea>
<div>Clique para mudar a fonte</div>
```

Comment: acredito que o op por ter apenas colocado a tag [tag:javascript] na pergunta, o ideal é respostas que resolvam utilizando apenas javascript, pois você não tem certeza se ele poderá utilizar [tag:jquery] ou que ele deva utilizar.

Comment: Paulo, na verdade dei uma olhada no perfil dele e percebi que ele usa sim o Jquery. Por mais que a tag seja javascript tenho certeza que isso irá ajudar ele ou qualquer outra pessoa que futuramente tenha a mesma necessidade de pesquisa. Os colegas ja responderam usando apenas javascript e acredito que isso é uma excelente forma de deixar um assunto bem completo em todas as situações. Lembre-se: Jquery também é javascript.

Comment: Eu quis dizer que talvez ele não possa incluir a biblioteca jQuery no projeto em questão que ele está trabalhando, não quis dizer que ele não use jQuery em geral. Pois JQuery é uma biblioteca javascript que auxilia bastante coisa, porém nem sempre em todos os casos você pode ou deve utiliza-la no seu projeto. No meu ponto de vista, eu acredito ser mais organizado haver respostas apenas javascript aqui pois futuramente abre a possibilidade de haver a pergunta "Como alterar fonte no textarea usando JQuery" e então ter mais conteudo/respostas referentes nela. Mas é a minha opinião apenas

Comment: Se você não for fazer um grande framework, ou sistema complexo, ou um site gigante, considere usar Javascript puro.  JQUERY: USAR OU NÃO USAR? https://www.revista-programar.info/artigos/jquery-usar-ou-nao-usar/

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.getElementById('meuTextarea').style.fontFamily = 'nomequalquer';
document.getElementById("meuTextarea").style.fontSize = "xx-large";
document.getElementById("meuTextarea").style.color = "red";
document.getElementById("meuTextarea").style.wordSpacing = "10px"
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'nomequalquer';
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/tangerine/v8/HGfsyCL5WASpHOFnouG-RFtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2);
}
```

```html
<textarea id=meuTextarea>Olá George, gostou?</textarea>
```

Você pode baixar a fonte e publicar no servidor.

Exemplo com .TTF

CSS

```
@font-face {
  font-family: nomequalquer;
  //baixe a fonte e publique no seu servidor
  src: url('SANTO___.TTF');
}
```

JavaScript

```
  document.getElementById('meuTextarea').style.fontFamily = 'nomequalquer';
  document.getElementById("meuTextarea").style.fontSize = "xx-large";
```

> Algumas outras propriedades:

- fontStyle - estilo de caracteres. Valores: normal, italic, oblique e inherit
  exemplo  `document.getElementById("meuTextarea").style.fontStyle = "italic";`
- fontWeight - caracteres em peso negrito ou leve. Valores: bold, bolder, lighter, normal, 100, 200 ....
  exemplo  `document.getElementById("meuTextarea").style.fontWeight = "bold";`
- textAlign - alinhamento horizontal. Valores: center, justify, left e right.
  exemplo  `document.getElementById("meuTextarea").style.textAlign = "center";`
- letterSpacing - espaçamento entre os caracteres. Valores: normalmente em unidades.
  exemplo  `document.getElementById("meuTextarea").style.letterSpacing = "1.2em";`
- wordSpacing - espaçamento entre as palavras. Valores: normalmente em unidades.
  exemplo  `document.getElementById("meuTextarea").style.wordSpacing = "20px";`

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelector('textarea').style.fontFamily = 'Impact';
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando apenas [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) conforme a tag da sua pergunta e presumindo que você usa apenas um textarea:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].style.fontFamily = 'Verdana';
```

```html
<textarea>Teste</textarea>
```

Caso você tenha mais de um textarea na sua página, você pode definir um ID ou um Name para o seu textarea, e então poderá acessa-lo e altera-lo diretamente desta forma:

Vamos supor que você colocou um id `meuTextarea`no seu textarea:

```js
document.getElementById('meuTextarea').style.fontFamily = 'Verdana';
```

```html
<textarea id=meuTextarea>Teste</textarea>
```

Comment: certo mais se no caso eu queira importar a fonte

Comment: Neste caso você deve olhar as respostas para esta pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127400/3082